# Conditions on Features with ComponentGroupRefs in Wix

Tags: c#, installation, wix, windows-installer

I have the following code:

```
    <Feature Id='SMSGatewayFeatures' Title='SMS Gateway Product Feature' Level='2'>
        <Condition Level='1'>INSTALLSMSGATEWAYSERVICE</Condition>
        <ComponentGroupRef Id='group_SMSGATEWAYWSWEBAPPFILES' />
    </Feature>
```

Assuming an INSTALLLEVEL of 1, I noticed that the Condition above gets evaluated when I have INSTALLSMSGATEWAYSERVICE set to 1. Additionally, the installer will properly set the install level of this Feature to 1

But there is a problem: although the install level of this Feature gets set to 1, no Component from group_SMSGATEWAYWSWEBAPPFILES gets installed. What is going on?

Not sure if it matters, but here is how the fragment is set up:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="group_SMSGATEWAYWSWEBAPPFILES">
      <ComponentRef Id="comp_SMSGATEWAYWSWEBAPPFILES_0" />
      <ComponentRef Id="comp_SMSGATEWAYWSWEBAPPFILES_1" />
      ...
    </ComponentGroup>
    <DirectoryRef Id="WEBDIR">
    <Directory Id="dir_SMSGatewayWS_0" Name="SMSGatewayWS">
        <Component Id="comp_SMSGATEWAYWSWEBAPPFILES_0" DiskId="1" KeyPath="yes" Guid="38B3FC5F-B556-40C1-BF8F-5EF41E29B345">
          <File Id="file_SMSGATEWAYWSWEBAPPFILES_0" Source="D:\somepath\mssccprj.scc" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="comp_SMSGATEWAYWSWEBAPPFILES_1" DiskId="1" KeyPath="yes" Guid="3C0B8CE2-1973-424D-868A-C2C074F254S3">
          <File Id="file_SMSGATEWAYWSWEBAPPFILES_1" Source="D:\somepath\Service1.asmx" />
        </Component>
        ...
    </Directory>
    </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    </Wix>
```

Comment: Do the components use any conditions? Did you try creating a log to see why they are not installed? http://setupanddeployment.com/debugging/msi-log/

Comment: As Feature level is 2 and Condition Level is 1, i think this might be problem. Set Feature level to 1 and try .....

Comment: Cosmin, frate, the components do not use any conditions. I tried creating a log but it didn't show any errors. Vinay, you can't do that. Conditions on features change the level of the feature to the level you specify. You can't change a feature to the level its already at by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to my issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451515/installlevel-doesnt-install-a-feature/8478972#8478972), in another thread that I started which actually ties in with this one. In case anybody has the same problem and needs to find a solution, its there.