# INSTALLLEVEL Doesn't Install a Feature

Tags: c#, windows, installation, wix, windows-installer

I have two features:

```
    <Feature Id='BaseProductFeatures' Title='Feature 1' Level='1'>
        <ComponentRef Id='WebAppVDirComponent'/>
        <ComponentRef Id='someVDirComponent'/>
        <ComponentRef Id='anotherWCFVDirComponent'/>
        <ComponentGroupRef Id='group_IMPORTFOLDERFILES'/>
        <ComponentGroupRef Id='group_WINSERVERFILES'/>
    </Feature>

    <Feature Id='SMSGWFeature' Title='Feature 2' Level='2'>
        <ComponentGroupRef Id='group_SMSGWWEBAPPFILES'/>
    </Feature>
```

Before the install, I change the INSTALLLEVEL to 2 using a Custom Action:

```
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult ChangeInstallLevel(Session session) {
        session["INSTALLLEVEL"] = "2";
        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
```

The value gets set, but Feature 2 (SMSGWFeature) does not get installed. Why is that? I don't see any of the Components in the ComponentGroupRef, group_SMSGWWEBAPPFILES, get installed in the directory I would expect to see them in. But the installer will work if I set the Level of Feature 2 (SMSGWFeature) to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, log files don't say anything and I set the INSTALLLEVEL before InstallValidate (I set it in the user interface before the install). As for overhead, it all happens quickly on this slow machine but then again its a custom action I'm using in the UI on a next button click. But I found out what the issue is and how to work around it.

With reference to [this link](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1910), it is too late to change the INSTALLLEVEL from the UI because the INSTALLLEVEL is taken into account under the CostFinalize standard action, and the CostFinalize standard action gets executed before I have time to let the user pick his features and call my action. Cosmin, I don't think the INSTALLLEVEL matters before InstallValidate, it seems to be much sooner that it matters, in this case its before CostFinalize that it gets taken into account.

What I had to do was as follows...

I changed my second feature to allow it to be absent:

```
<Feature Id='BaseProductFeatures' Title='Feature 1' Level='1'>
    <ComponentRef Id='WebAppVDirComponent'/>
    <ComponentRef Id='someVDirComponent'/>
    <ComponentRef Id='anotherWCFVDirComponent'/>
    <ComponentGroupRef Id='group_IMPORTFOLDERFILES'/>
    <ComponentGroupRef Id='group_WINSERVERFILES'/>
</Feature>

<Feature Id='SMSGWFeature' Title='Feature 2' Level='2' Absent='allow'>
    <ComponentGroupRef Id='group_SMSGWWEBAPPFILES'/>
</Feature>
```

I changed my custom action to either enable or disable the feature:

```
foreach (FeatureInfo aFeature in session.Features) {
    if (session["INSTALLSMSGATEWAYSERVICE"] == "" && aFeature.Name == "SMSGWFeature") {
        aFeature.RequestState = Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.InstallState.Absent;
    }
    else if (session["INSTALLSMSGATEWAYSERVICE"] == "1" && aFeature.Name == "SMSGWFeature") {
        aFeature.RequestState = Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.InstallState.Local;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your custom action is executed before [InstallValidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) action in [InstallExecuteSequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Setting INSTALLLEVEL after InstallValidate doesn't affect anything.

Also, a [verbose installation log](http://setupanddeployment.com/debugging/msi-log/) greatly helps in determining if and why a feature or component is not installed. Simply search for InstallValidate in the log and check the feature and component states and install actions.

Comment: +1. BTW, @Alexandru, it's quite an overhead to author C# custom action just to set a property. Take a look at SetProperty element: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_setproperty.htm